# ESXi host disk partition information using pysphere

Tags: python, vmware

I need to get the information of the partitions on the scsi disks with pysphere. Can anybody please tell me how can i do it. I am new to it.
so far what i know is i can get the disk devices with following:

```
props = VIProperty(server, host_mor)
scsiLuns = props.config.storageDevice.scsiLun
```

But this only gives me the scsi device not the partition information in it.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Does it have to be  pysphere? Have you tried powercli?

Comment: pysphere only. powercli wont do for me.